# How can I use C++ to write to an opened terminal?

Tags: c++, cygwin, executable

I am trying to communicate with a program (xfoil) and read and write to its command line. Xfoil can take many parameters in its built in terminal.

I can open the program using system("path") but how do I input more commands to the opened xfoil terminal? Once I can do that I can do all that I need to do with the terminal commands.

Comment: Writing to an opened terminal is easy (I use std::ofstream).  Writing to an application 'running' in that terminal is also easy, but different.  All the alternatives I am familiar seem to be Posix or Linux,  and not C++. I prefer the posix function 'popen'.  It is not c++ and is not a c++ library, but Linux and other OS's support posix functions.  You should also Investigate Linux fork and pipe, if you 'fork' a process, you can connect output to input pipes, and write commands, as well as receive reactions through the pipes.  These are parts of Linux and Posix, not a library.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

[Tiny Process Library](https://gitlab.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library) is a good library for interacting with processes.

Checkout example 6 and 7 for giving commands to a process. https://gitlab.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library/blob/master/examples.cpp

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I am trying to avoid using a, library. Is there a simple way to just write to it without having to include one?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use C++ to write to an opened terminal

On linux, there are 7+ steps:

1) open a terminal

```
   I find ctrl-alt t   most convenient
   press and hold ctrl and alt, then press t

   There is also a selection LXTerminal on a mouse menu 

   Note - There is a way for your program to open a 'default' terminal, 
   and c++ can use the technique, but it is not c++, and I always seem to 
   need to change the defaults for my use.
```

2) using the terminal, you manually find the name of the terminal by:

```
   type the command "tty" into the terminal

Typical response on my system:

   hostname@username:~$ tty
   /dev/pts/1
```

The terminal name is always of the form "/dev/pts/x" on my Linux system, where x is a number.

3) For my programs (that use a second terminal), my code accepts the x portion (of the terminal response) as command parameter 1, and uses that parameter to create a path file name (PFN) to the terminal.

```
std::string     aTermPFN    = "/dev/pts/";  // partial address

aTermPFN        += argv[1];  // ouput tty identified by argv[1] 

// creating /dev/pts/<argv[1]>
// thus creating PFN of "/dev/pts/1"
```

4) My code typically provides a confirmation of the number during creation. (recommended)

```
std::cout << "accessing '" << aTermPFN 
          << "' with std::ofstream " << std::endl;
```

5) and then creates (or attempts to create) the ofstream object

```
std::ofstream*  ansiTerm = new std::ofstream(aTermPFN);
```

6) and perform a few checks on it ...

```
if (!ansiTerm->is_open())
{
   std::cerr << "Can not access '" << aTermPFN << "'" << std::endl;
   assert(0); // abort 
}
```

7) When done with term, be sure to clean up

```
ansiTerm->close(); 
delete ansiTerm;
```

// you can avoid the delete if you use an appropriate smart pointer.

Now all output to that 2nd terminal uses the 'ansiTerm' object, I happen to use a more generic term in that code (not a pointer, but reference) :  "termRef".

Examples of use

```
// mostly, in the app where these sample exist, I output text at computed
// screen locations

// ansi terminals provide goto row col ansi functions
//   the style is simply position the cursor, 
termRef << m_ansi.gotoRC(3, col) << ss.str() << std::flush;
// then output text-----------------^^^^^^^^ (ss is stringstream)

// ansi terminals can clear 
void clearScr() { termRef << m_ansi.clrscr() << std::flush; }

// ansi terminals can draw simple borders (not-fancy)
{  // across top      gotoRC (int row, int col )
   termRef << m_ansi.gotoRC ( tlcRow, tlcCol+1);
   for   ( int i=0; i<borderWidth; ++i) termRef << m_acs.HLINE;
   termFlush();
}
```